# ActiveX not installed after confirm installation prompt

Tags: deployment, activex

I have a cabinet to deploy an activex inside my site.
The installation prompts correctly and when i click "confirm" seem that activex will be installed, but unfortunatly is not...its ask me for installation every time...

How install works?
There is a way to see errors of installation?

My cabinet .inf file is this:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0

[Add.Code]
Setup.msi=Setup.msi

[Deployment]
InstallScope=operator

[Setup.msi]
file-win32-x86=thiscab
clsid={72645213-AEA3-49E1-B65E-268101ADF535}
FileVersion=1,0,0,0

[Setup Hooks]
RunSetup=RunSetup

[RunSetup]
run="""msiexec.exe""" /i """%EXTRACT_DIR%\Setup.msi""" /qn
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view ActiveX intallation log you can use Code Download Log Viewer. [Download from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/3/683DB9FE-8D61-4A3C-B7B8-3169FF70AE9F/cdllogvw.exe)

Other than that, maybe try running msi without /qn and check that installation